# Waiting for react state to update in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

How can I make sure that `handleOpen` only executes after all the states (`nameError`, `emailError`, `messageError`) have been updated? My problem is that since state doesn't update immediately, sometimes `handleOpen` executes when it shouldn't.

```
const handleSend = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (name === "") {
  setNameError(true);
}
if (email === "") {
  setEmailError(true);
  setEmailErrorMessage("Please type your email!");
}
if (!email.includes("@")) {
  setEmailError(true);
  setEmailErrorMessage("Invalid email address");
}
if (message === "") {
  setMessageError(true);
}
if (!nameError && !emailError && !messageError) {
  handleOpen();
}
```

};

Comment: why not just do this `if (email !== "" && !email.includes("@") && message !== "") { handleOpen();}`

Comment: Do you ***need*** to save the errors to state at all? Just check the error conditions and if there are no errors conditionally call `handleOpen`. If you need to persist the errors locally then abstract the logic into a validator function and conditionally set state ***or*** call `handleOpen` based on validation result. Can you provide a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we understand the use case more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are struggling with JS Event Loop. React states will update after an event loop is finished. So you can't expect them to update immediately in your handler function.

However there are some other solutions like using setTimeout(..., 0) to cheat the event loop, which is not going to help you in this case.

Here you need to refactor the handler method to handle the error states in your function scope and set the final result to the error states.

```js
const handleSend = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const errors = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  };
  
  if (name === "") {
    errors.name = "Please enter your name";
  }

  if (email === "") {
    errors.email = "Please type your email!";
  }

  if (!email.includes("@")) {
    errors.email = "Invalid email address";
  }

  if (message === "") {
    errors.email = "Please enter a message";
  }

  setNameError(!!errors.name);
  setNameErrorMessage(errors.name);
  setEmailError(!!errors.email);
  setEmailErrorMessage(errors.email);
  setMessageError(!!errors.message);
  setMessageErrorMessage(errors.message);

  if (Object.values(errors).filter(Boolean).length === 0) {
     handleOpen();
  }
}
```

I strongly suggest refactoring the error handling process in your application. Your solution and the one I wrote here is not efficient at all.

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use react's `useRef` hook, for its not reactive, i.e doesnt cause page rerender so that you're sure

```
if (!nameError && !emailError && !messageError) {
  handleOpen();
}
```

executes when the right in the order you wanted just as i'll show below

```
const setNameError = useRef(null);
const setEmailError = useRef({value : false, message : ''});
const setMessageError = useRef(null);
const handleSend = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (name === "") {
  setNameError.current = true;
}
if (email === "") {
  setEmailError.current.value = true;
  setEmailError.current.message = "Please type your email!";
}
if (!email.includes("@")) {
  setEmailError.current.value = true;
  setEmailError.current.message = "Invalid email address";
}
if (message === "") {
  setMessageError.current = true;
}
if (!setNameError.current && !setRmailError.current && !setMessageError.current) {
  handleOpen();
}
};
```

i have used bad naming conversion so as to go with your example, but in real life you wont chose `setNameError` for a variable name as I've done but maybe you'll do `nameError`

Comment: If OP needs setting the errors to trigger a rerender to display them then exclusively using React refs might not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a whole refactor on how you are handling the errors, but answering your question, you could do just this:

```
const handleSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const isNameEmpty = name === "";
    const isEmailEmpty = email === "";
    const isEmailAtMissing = !email.includes("@");
    const isMessageEmpty = message === "";

    setNameError(isNameEmpty);
    setEmailError(isEmailEmpty || isEmailAtMissing);
    setEmailErrorMessage(isEmailEmpty ? "Please type your email!" : "Invalid email address");
    setMessageError(isMessageEmpty);

    if ([isNameEmpty, emailError, emailError].some(value => !!value)) {
        handleOpen()
    }
}
```

If you save the "errors" in variables, then you make sure you are checking the last values you are using in the states.

Answer (score 0):

The best scenario you could follow for these kinds of problems is that you create another state or even a constant that has the checks for the validation and then put it in the useEffect to check if the value is changed and then whenever it is changed, you check it if it holds true or no. for better understanding you can do like this:

```js
const [wholeValidate, setWholeValidate] = useState(false);

const handleSend = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (name === "") {
  setNameError(true);
}
if (email === "") {
  setEmailError(true);
  setEmailErrorMessage("Please type your email!");
}
if (!email.includes("@")) {
  setEmailError(true);
  setEmailErrorMessage("Invalid email address");
}
if (message === "") {
  setMessageError(true);
}

if (!nameError && !emailError && !messageError) {
  setWholeValidate(true);  
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(wholeValidate) {handleOpen();}
}, [wholeValidate])
```